# Adding Multiple Panels with Different Sizes in One Frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am trying to add more panels to my frame, but the program seems to ignore all the other panels than the first one I added. How should I add the panels?

I have checked other people's questions and their answers, but none of them seemed to be the solution to mine.

```
frame = new JFrame("Hey");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel mid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,7));
JPanel top = new JPanel();

frame.add(top);
frame.add(mid);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The program ignores the "top" panel, along with the buttons I added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JFrame documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.

So you should use the [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) regions in order to add your JPanels to the JFrame's content pane like this:

```
frame.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(mid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Otherwise, the BorderLayout will default to adding everything to the `CENTER` region:

> As a convenience, BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant CENTER:
>
> ```
> Panel p2 = new Panel();
> p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
> p2.add(new TextArea());  // Same as p.add(new TextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
> ```

and you will only see the JPanel added last because:

> Each region may contain no more than one component